# How to convert hh:mm:ss to seconds in SQL Server with more than 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table name `tblAttend` in which one column named `WorkHrs` is of datatype `varchar`.

The result of simple select query is

[image]

I sum this column's value and get result in seconds my query is

```
select sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', WorkHrs )) 
from tblAttend
```

and it shows this output:

[image]

Now the issue is, when sum of `WorkHrs` is greater than 24 hours it will throw an error:

[image]

What can you suggest to get around this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's correct. SQL Server has a `time` data type that represents a *time of day*, **not** a *time span*. As such, this type doesn't have to deal with negative values, nor values greater than 24 hours, nor deal with the concept of adding two such values together. None of those make sense for a *time of day*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try splitting each time into its component parts by converting the time to a string and then multiplying by the number of seconds relevant to each part.

Data conversion to integer is implicit

```
select Sum(Left(WorkHrs,2) * 3600 + substring(WorkHrs, 4,2) * 60 + substring(WorkHrs, 7,2))
from tblAttend
```

Comment: This is very simple approach, Now its working on current set of inputs. Thanks a lot

Comment: @merrais To work with hours above 99, use this:  
  
`SELECT SUM(SUBSTRING(WorkHrs, 1, CHARINDEX(':', WorkHrs)-1) * 3600 + SUBSTRING(WorkHrs, CHARINDEX(':', WorkHrs)+1, 2) * 60 + RIGHT(WorkHrs, 2))`

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
DECLARE @DURATION TIME = '01:43:24'

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1/1/1900', CONVERT(DATETIME, @DURATION))
```

Comment: TIME cannot represent over 24 hours  [T-Sql TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016), so this doesn't work for the original question.  But if your times don't go over 24 hours, this can be simplified further: SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, @DURATION); No need for the 1900 literal or CONVERT.

Comment: Shortest solution by @TomFp above, for converting a TIME column into seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented the following function to use it in the management of my projects :

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Seconds]    Script Date:     10/6/2017 12:00:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*
select [dbo].[Seconds]('24:00:00'),(24*3600)
select [dbo].[Seconds]('102:56:08'),(102*3600+56*60+8)
*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Seconds] (@Time as varchar(50))
RETURNS int
BEGIN
declare @S int, @H int
set @H=cast(SUBSTRING(@Time,1,CHARINDEX(':',@Time)-1) as int)
IF @H<24
set @S=DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', @Time)
ELSE BEGIN
    set @H=@H-23
    set @Time = '23'+SUBSTRING(@Time,CHARINDEX(':',@Time),LEN(@Time)-2)
    set @S = (@H*3600)+DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', @Time)
END
RETURN @S
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
SELECT Sec=SUM((DATEPART(HOUR,column name)*3600)+(DATEPART(MINUTE,column name)*60)+(DATEPART(Second,column name)))
FROM [TableName]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `WorkHrs` to `DATETIME` first, then perform the `DATEDIFF`:

```
WITH Cte(WorkHrs) AS(
    SELECT CAST('02:29:11' AS VARCHAR(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('21:00:00' AS VARCHAR(10)) UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('25:20:02' AS VARCHAR(10))
),
CteConvert(dt) AS(
    SELECT  
        DATEADD(
            SECOND, 
            CAST(SUBSTRING(WorkHrs, 7, 2) AS INT), 
            DATEADD(
                MINUTE, 
                CAST(SUBSTRING(WorkHrs, 4, 2) AS INT), 
                DATEADD(
                    HOUR, 
                    CAST(SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,1, 2) AS INT), 
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, dt)),
    -- Formatted to hh:mm:sss
    RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, dt)) / (60 * 60))), 2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(2), (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, dt)) / 60) % 60)), 2) + ':' + 
    RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(2), SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, dt)) % 60)),2) 
FROM CteConvert
```

Comment: Thanks for your time i got very simple solution from @Ewan post,

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;with cte as (
 select
    total =Sum(Left(WorkHrs,2) * 3600 + substring(WorkHrs, 4,2) * 60 + substring(WorkHrs, 7,2))
 from tblAttend
 )
 select
    total [Total Time in Seconds],
    (total / 3600) [Total Time Hour Part],
    ((total % 3600) / 60) [Total Time Minute Part],
    (total % 60) [Total Time Second Part] 
 from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can isolate each part of the time (hour, minute and second) and than sum what you need, please take a look:

```
declare @tbl table(WorkHrs VARCHAR(8))
insert into @tbl(WorkHrs) values ('02:29:11')
insert into @tbl(WorkHrs) values ('25:00:11')
-- Sum in minutes
SELECT TRY_CAST(([HOURS] * 60) + [MINUTES] + ([SECOND] / 60) AS INT) as TotalInMinutes
FROM (
SELECT 
    -- Use this aproach to get separated values 
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,1,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [HOURS],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,4,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [MINUTES],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,7,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [SECOND] -- probably you can ignore this one
    FROM @tbl
)
tbl
-- Or try to sum in seconds
SELECT TRY_CAST(([HOURS] * 3600) + ([MINUTES] * 60) + [SECOND] AS INT) as TotalInSeconds
FROM (
SELECT 
    -- Use this aproach to get separated values 
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,1,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [HOURS],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,4,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [MINUTES],
    SUBSTRING(WorkHrs,7,CHARINDEX(':',WorkHrs)-1) AS [SECOND]
    FROM @tbl
)
tbl
```

It will return like this to you:

[image]

I hope it can help

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the TIME_TO_SEC function:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(WorkHrs) FROM tblAttend;
```

Comment: `TIME_TO_SEC` is a MySQL function, not a SQL Server function.