# SUM of a group of time differences in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to sum all the time differences to show the total hours worked.

```
select 
    aaaa
from 
    employee B 
inner join 
    (select 
         s.emp_reader_id,
         Sum(case  when  s.in_time is not null and s.out_time is not null  and s.shift_type_id=5 and  LOWER(DATENAME(dw, [att_date]))='friday'then   
cast(datediff(minute,'00:00:00', '23:59:59') / 60 +
     (datediff(minute,'00:00:00', '23:59:59') % 60 / 100.0) as decimal(7, 4)
           ) end) as aaaa
     from 
         Daily_attendance_data s 
     left outer join 
         employee bb on s.emp_reader_id = bb.emp_reader_id
     where 
         att_date between '2018-10-01' and '2018-10-31' 
         and s.emp_reader_id = 1039
     group by 
         s.emp_reader_id) A on B.emp_reader_id = A.emp_reader_id
```

Current output:

```
aaaa
47.1800
```

which gives the list of times by hours but then I want to sum it up to a grand total.

It would just total

Sample data :

```
23:59
23:59
```

Expected output:

```
47.58
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  i have default values as  23:59 in two rows and i have to sum and need expected output as 47.58

Comment: What's your data type?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should convert all times to seconds, calculate the SUM then convert the total to `HH:mm:ss`.

1. Calculate The SUM of seconds

   ```
   DECLARE @TimeinSecond as integer = 0

   select @TimeinSecond = Sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', [WorkHrs]))
   from Daily_attendance_data
   ```
2. Convert the HH:mm:ss Format

   ```
   SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
   RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TimeinSecond / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
   RIGHT('0' + CAST(@TimeinSecond % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)
   ```

**References**

- [How to convert hh:mm:ss to seconds in SQL Server with more than 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425204/how-to-convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-in-sql-server-with-more-than-24-hours/31425503)
- [SQL SERVER – Convert Seconds to Hour : Minute : Seconds Format](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/17/sql-server-convert-seconds-to-hour-minute-seconds-format/)

Answer (score 2):

If your date type is DateTime.

you can try to let your value split two part.

1. `hours` get value need to condider carry from minutes so do `SUM(intpart) + SUM(floatpart) / 60`
2. `minutes` get value from `SUM(floatpart) % 60`

look like this.

```
SELECT concat(SUM(intpart) + SUM(floatpart) / 60,':', SUM(floatpart) % 60)
FROM (
    SELECT cast(SUBSTRING (cast(col as varchar),0,3) as int) intpart,
           cast(SUBSTRING (cast(col as varchar),CHARINDEX(':',col) +1,2)as int) floatpart
    FROM T
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f91f8108c6ca7904df8df562d67f8d58)